# Executar uma função enquanto segura botão, parar quando soltar

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova

Como executar uma função quando o usuário segurar um botão e parar de executar quando o usuário soltar o botão. 
Como acontece no *WhatsApp* quando você vai gravar um áudio...

Comment: Mostre o código que vc já desenvolveu usando um botão para começar a gravar e um para parar para que possamos adaptá-lo a sua necessidade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
var intervalId = 0;

// Define o evento de clicar com o botão do mouse no #click
$('#click').on('mousedown', function() {
    intervalId = setInterval(hold, 500); // Define um intervalo que a função será chamanda em 0.5 segundos
});

// Define o evento de soltar ao documento
$(document).on('mouseup', release);

// Função que será chamada com delay de 0.5 segundos
function hold() {
    console.log('Pressionando...');
}

// Função que será chamada quando soltar o botão
function release() {
    if(intervalId != 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId); // Limpa o intervalo registrado anteriormente
        intervalId = 0;
        
        console.log('Soltou!');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="click">Clique e segure</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que as ações necessárias sejam a abaixo, falta é implementar o código de sua gravação, veja se lhe ajuda:

```js
$(function() {

  $("button").mouseup(function() {
    $("#gravando").text('Não');
    // Sua lógica para parar a gravação
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $("#gravando").text('Não');
    // Sua lógica para parar a gravação
  }).mousedown(function() {
    $("#gravando").text('Sim');
    // Sua lógica para iniciar a gravação    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Está Gravando?</p>
<div id="gravando">Não</div>

<button>Gravar</button>
```

Acredito que atenda a sua solicitação.

Comment: Não funcionou, na verdade eu quero fazer exatamente oque o whatsApp faz para gravar os áudios, eu já consigo gravar os áudios porém usando um botão para começar a gravar e um para parar. Eu quero que grave enquanto estou segurando o botão e pare de gravar quando eu soltar o botão;

Comment: Alterei o código para corresponder melhor ao que precisa, veja se é isso mesmo.

Comment: É exatamente isso que estou tentando fazer, o problema é que estou utilizando o PhoneGap, e estes eventos : mouseup mouseout e mousedown, não funcionam.

Comment: Consegui: Apenas mudei o evento 'mousedown' por 'touchstart' e o 'mouseout' por 'touchend'..

Answer (score 0):

Consegui com a ajuda do Bruno Rigolon, 
Apenas troquei os eventos 'mousedown' e 'mouseup' por touchstart e touchend pois estou utilizando o phonegap.

O código fica dessa maneira:

```
$('#btn_gravar').on('touchstart',function(){
    //Inicia o processo de gravação
});

 $('#btn_gravar').on('touchend',function(){
    //Para o processo de gravação
 });
```